# Use Winforms Enums in .Net Standard 2.0

Tags: c#, .net, .net-standard

I have a solution simplified as follows:

MyProject.Models (trying to upgrade from framework 4.7.2 to standard 2.0)

- MyModel.cs
- IUIController.cs

MyProject.UI (Winforms app, targets framework 4.7.2)

- MyView.cs
- UIController.cs

The content of the files is:

MyModel.cs

```
public class MyModel
{
    public static int ExecuteCommand(System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand cmd)
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

MyView.cs

```
public class MyView
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        using var cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand();
        MyProject.Models.MyModel.ExecuteCommand(cmd);
    }
}
```

IUIController.cs

```
public interface IUIController
{
    DialogResult AskQuestion(string question);
}
```

UIController .cs

```
public class UIController : MyProject.Models.IUIController
{
    DialogResult AskQuestion(string question)
    {
        return MessageBox.Show(question);
    }
}
```

Obviously this is not working as is wenn switching the Models project to net standard.
DialogResult is not defined.

The idea is to simulate what Microsoft does with numerous of his own libraries.
In this example: System.Data.SqlClient.
The type System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand is defined in the .net framework in the System.Data.dll.
This dll does not run on .net standard.
Instead they created a nuget package, compatible with .net standard.
This package contains a standard dll that defines all the types in the right namespace, but all implementations simply throw PlattformNotSupportedExceptions.
And it contains an empty .net framework dll that contains absolutely nothing.
When compiling, VS recognises all the types and methods in net standard. In runtime the application is run with the empty dll and the app seems to know that the types come from the .net framework itself.
In the end it runs fine.

So it did exactly the same for DialogResult:
A nuget "MyWinforms" containing:

- net standard:
  DialogResult.cs with the enum exactly like he is defines in Winforms (same namespace, same values, ...)
- net framework:
  *nothing*

I now can compile MyProject.Model in .net standard, but not MyProject.UI.
The UIControler class does not compile.

In c# the message is:
Reference to type 'DialogResult' claims it is defined in 'MyWinforms', but it could not be found.

In VB.NET it is:
Import of type 'DialogResult' from assembly or module 'MyWinforms.dll' failed.

Any ideas why in case of System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand VS recognizes that these types are actualy the same, but does not recognize that my enum is supposed to be the same too ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found it. I have to use the [TypeForwardedTo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.typeforwardedtoattribute?view=net-7.0) Attribute to forward the enum from the empty framework-targeting dll to the enum inside the .net framework.